# How to download a detailed view report in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, button, download, report, oracle-apex

I have created a page with master detail report on Oracle Apex version 18.1. I am trying to download the reports through actions menu but I am only able to download the master report. If I click download for the detailed report, its generating an empty file even when data is present. I have also tried creating a manual download button but that is also generating an empty file. Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: How did you create the master/detail and what type is it?

Comment: Also, run a quick test by creating a new app. Then add a new master/detail on dept/emp. Does that work as expected?